# Running SAS code from Excel

Tags: excel, sas, vba

I have multiple SAS codes that I run monthly. I would like to have an excel spreadsheet that contains all of the code and from which each piece of code can be run.

Firstly, is there just a simple way of doing this? I assume it would just call the code location and run it from there? Are there particular references that I need?

I found this piece of code and have been trying to use it, but I think something is wrong as it is telling me the license is expired but the code works when I run it in excel.

Here is the VBA code:

```
Sub RunSAS()
'--> Verify Run Request (Exit If Cancelled)
a = MsgBox("Run " & ActiveCell.Value & "?", vbOKCancel, "Run SAS Program Confirmation")
If a = vbCancel Then
Exit Sub
End If
'--> Run SAS Program
Z = Shell("C:\Program Files\SAS\x86\SASFoundation\9.3\sas.exe -initstmt '%include """ &     ActiveCell.Value & """ / source2; run;'", vbNormalFocus)

'--> If Requested, Insert Run Time/Date In FIFO Order
' ('Run History' Must Appear In First Row Of Column To Right Of Program Name)
If UCase$(Trim(Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column + 1).Value)) = "RUN HISTORY" Then Cells   (ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRightCells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1).Select
Selection.Copy Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column - 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
False, Transpose:=False
Selection.Value = Date & " " & Time()
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column - 1).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If

End Sub
```

The SAS code I am trying to execute is very simple and just attempts to send myself an email.

```
%INC 'H:\sasconnect\idwapid.inc';
OPTIONS COMAMID=tcp;

FILENAME RLINK '\\int\groupdata\IDW\sasscript\SAS93\sasap6\prod\Res_sasapv93_prod.scr';

%let host=idwap1 17554;
%let server=host;
SIGNON remote=&server;

RSUBMIT;

*** send email ***;
FILENAME eml2 email TO= ("a.m@company.com.au") SUBJECT="Test";   
DATA _NULL_;
  FILE eml2;            
  PUT "Email 3";
RUN;

endrsubmit;
signoff;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of the "SAS® Add-In for Microsoft Office" product? details available at http://support.sas.com/software/products/addin/